# Youtube Api: Can't get addEventListener to work in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

I am trying to run a function every time the player state changes but onStateChange is not firing when I use the following code in my extension.

```
function onPlayerStateChange( newState ) {
    console.log( "New state: " + newState );
}

player = document.getElementById( "movie_player" );
player.addEventListener( "onStateChange", "onPlayerStateChange" );
```

It runs fine when I run it through the chrome javascript console but for some reason I have not been able to get it to work with my extension.

This is the relevant part of the manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
  "matches": [ "*://*.youtube.com/watch*" ],
  "js": [ "jquery.js", "page.js" ]
} ],
```

And this is a part of page.js:

```
function onPlayerStateChange( newState ) {
    console.log( "New state: " + newState );
}

player = document.getElementById( "movie_player" );
player.addEventListener( "onStateChange", "onPlayerStateChange" );
```

Comment: Try player.addEventListener( "onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);

Comment: @方觉 You can't do this. The Flash code in the player finds the callback function via `window['whateverFunctionNameYouPassed']`. You can't pass a function reference like with the normal `addEventListener` calls. You could always generate a random symbol and bind the function to *that* however.

Comment: @Gsx You probably need to define the `onPlayerStateChange` function within the scope of the website's window. e.g: `targetWindow['onPlayerStateChange'] = function(newState) { ... }` where targetWindow is the DOM window your extension is targeting.